# How to install Redis - executables missing after make

Tags: ubuntu, installation, redis

Trying to install Redis on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.  I ran the steps from the website:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
```

And then:

```
sudo cp redis-server /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```

But these last two commands result in this:

```
cp: cannot stat `redis-server': No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  `make` and `make test` appear to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried `make install`?

Comment: Doh.  Yes, that did it.  With that, the other instructions listed on the website were unnecessary.  Submit that as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks, Flup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `make install` and smile, because life is good. :-)